# Ubuntu doesn't boot anymore: Failed to start PostgreSQL Cluster 10-main

Tags: boot, dual-boot, postgresql

I've been using Ubuntu for about one month on the concerned computer.
It always worked fine, but when I wanted to boot my computer today, I got following message: `Failed to start PostgreSQL Cluster 10-main`
The computer doesn't boot anymore.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: That's the only message?

Comment: Yes, it's the only "FAILED" log